# SQL Server Trace keeps outputting files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, audit, trace

A consultant has come and gone to do some audit on our SQL server, and has left a bit of a mess here. The problem is that he did things that we don't know anything about.

In the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` we get a few GB of .trc files, and they keep appearing and growing.

A `SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default) where property = 2` returns 2 lines:

```
1   2   \\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\audittrace20130910192403_347.trc
2   2   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_589.trc
```

`EXEC sp_trace_setstatus 1 ,0` says that we are not allowed to execute `sp_trace_setstatus`, even when logged as `sa`.

We have tried this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
sp_configure 'c2 audit mode', 0 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

It says that "the configuration option 'c2 audit mode' has gone from 0 to 0", but `exec sp_configure` tells us that the `run_value` of `c2 audit mode` is still 1.

We're a bit lost as to what we should do to stop the trace files to appear and grow.

Comment: Looks like we need to restart the SQL server to take the new config value into account. We'll see tomorrow, as we can't restart the server now.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `c2 audit mode` to 0, we had to restart the server... `RECONFIGURE` wasn't enough.